# Probability Dice Game! Help me!

Tags: probability

"Megan is selected to play a Megamillions game in which she can win a potentially unlimited amount of money. In this game, she repeatedly rolls a fair six-sided die, and the game ends as soon as she rolls a six. If roll 0 is a six, then she wins nothing; if roll 1 is a six, then she wins a total of 1^2 = 1 dollar; if roll 2 is a six, then she wins a total of 2^2=$4; and so on. What is the expected value of her winnings, in dollars?"

If anyone can help me figure this out that would be amazing!  Obviously there is a 1/6 chance that she rolls a six, but I'm not sure where to go from there!

Comment: This is the mean of a geometric distribution.

Answer (score 2):

If she wins n games, then she gets n^2 dollars.

The probability of winning 0 games is 1/6, as this is the chance her first roll is 6.

The probability of winning 1 game is 1/6*5/6, as she needs to win the first game and lose the second.

So the probability of winning n games is (5/6)^n*1/6. and the amount she wins is n^2, so the expectation is:

Sum from 0 to infinity of n^2*(5/6)^n*1/6
which comes out to be 55

Answer (score 0):

HINT: we have a geometric random variable $X\sim G(1/6)$ where $X$ represent the total number of throws of a game (the game ends when a six appear) what means that

$$\Pr[X=x]=\frac16\left(\frac56\right)^{x-1}$$

and the expected value of a discrete random variable $X$ is defined as

$$\Bbb E[X]=\sum_x x\Pr[X=x]$$

However we want to know the expected value of the amount of dollars that you can win per game, this is

$$\Bbb E[(X-1)^2]=\sum_{x\in\Bbb N} (x-1)^2\Pr[X=x]=\frac16\sum_{x\ge 0}x^2\left(\frac56\right)^x$$

Comment: But $\mathbb{E}[X]^2 \neq \mathbb{E}[X^2]$.

Comment: Yes @PeterShor ... I dont get what you try to say.

Comment: I'm saying the last line of your answer is wrong. The correct solution is 55.

Comment: @PeterShor oh, I understand, you are right, I will fix it.